# Unable to get session from FacebookRedirectLoginHelper() for Facebook PHP SDK 4

Tags: php, facebook, session

I've tried dozens of solutions but can't get a session from Facebook using the PHP SDK 4. Here are the two pages I'm using (I've tried the single page code before but right now have split them into two pages). The redirect page never returns a $_SESSION and the $session variable is always NULL. I would appreciate any help, thanks!

```
//loginFB.php
include 'vendor/autoload.php';

ob_start();
session_start();

// added in v4.0.5
use Facebook\FacebookHttpable;
use Facebook\FacebookCurl;
use Facebook\FacebookCurlHttpClient;
// added in v4.0.0
use Facebook\FacebookSession;
use Facebook\FacebookRedirectLoginHelper;
use Facebook\FacebookRequest;
use Facebook\FacebookResponse;
use Facebook\FacebookSDKException;
use Facebook\FacebookRequestException;
use Facebook\FacebookOtherException;
use Facebook\FacebookAuthorizationException;
use Facebook\GraphObject;
use Facebook\GraphSessionInfo;

$id = '???';
$secret = '???';
FacebookSession::setDefaultApplication($id, $secret);

$helper = new FacebookRedirectLoginHelper('http://facebook.example.com/handleFB.php');

echo 'There is no current session, please login here: ';
echo '<a href="' . $helper->getLoginUrl( array( 'email', 'user_friends' ) ) . '">Facebook</a>';
```

```
//handleFB.php
include 'vendor/autoload.php';

session_start();

// added in v4.0.5
use Facebook\FacebookHttpable;
use Facebook\FacebookCurl;
use Facebook\FacebookCurlHttpClient;
// added in v4.0.0
use Facebook\FacebookSession;
use Facebook\FacebookRedirectLoginHelper;
use Facebook\FacebookRequest;
use Facebook\FacebookResponse;
use Facebook\FacebookSDKException;
use Facebook\FacebookRequestException;
use Facebook\FacebookOtherException;
use Facebook\FacebookAuthorizationException;
use Facebook\GraphObject;
use Facebook\GraphSessionInfo;

$id = '???';
$secret = '???';

FacebookSession::setDefaultApplication($id, $secret);

$helper = new FacebookRedirectLoginHelper('http://facebook.example.com/handleFB.php');

try {
  $session = $helper->getSessionFromRedirect();
} catch(FacebookRequestException $ex) {
  // When Facebook returns an error
    echo 'error1';
} catch(\Exception $ex) {
  // When validation fails or other local issues
    echo 'error2';
}
if ($session) {
  echo 'Yeah!!';
}

var_dump($_SESSION);

var_dump($session);
```

Comment: Whatever the issue was, it stemmed from using a subdomain. Curious if anyone knows why this might be?